# optional property injection in new windsor 2.5.2

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

We were using:

http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/Castle.Facilities.OptionalPropertyInjection

but unfortunately it looks like it is not maintained anymore (svn is not availible).

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem now. Is there any new build in functionality in Windsor lib?

Comment: Hey, I'm the one that initially wrote that facility. What do you need with it?

Answer (score 1):

It has been [moved to github](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Projects/tree/master/facilities/trunk/src/OptionalPropertyInjection). It hasn't been updated in over a year, it'd be great if you could do it, should be easy to upgrade it to the latest version of Windsor.

Comment: sure thing - we already did this for our local version, if you could  give me some access info i will try to commit the changes. My e-mail: j.nowak@contempro.pl

Comment: @user483071: don't need any access information. Just fork the repository, commit the changes and send the team a pull request.

Comment: @user483071: if you're not familiar with git, you could attach the patch to a message in the dev mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel

Comment: Hey Mauricio, what happened to all the wiki articles from using.CastleWindsor. I wrote up a long one on this facility and can't find it anymore

Comment: @George: it should have been migrated to the new wiki: http://docs.castleproject.org/ . If it wasn't, ask on the dev mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but Windsor by default makes properties optional so if that's all you want it works OOTB

Comment: From the docs: "By default Castle Windsor attempts to resolve and inject any properties with public setters. This is not always a desirable functionality. Castle.Facilities.OptionalPropertyInjection allows you to define policies for which properties which will be injected and which will be ignored."

Comment: @Krysztof - It basically lets you set up strategies for which properties get injected and which don't. When I was working with Windsor it was necessary. Not sure now (we're using structuremap). Ping me on twitter (@togakangaroo) if you got questions.

Comment: we were using this because sometimes we are resolving our views (wpf app) and they have a lot of properties we didn't want to resolve automaticaly

Comment: @user483071 how do you determine which properties are to be set and which not? What tells them apart?

Comment: In my case I'm using Caliburn.Micro and Windsor is trying to find components that implement `IScreen` to satisfy the `ActiveItem` for a given screen. I don't want this to happen, because **I** call `ActivateItem()` when I've worked out what the `ActiveItem` should be. So it's okay for Windsor to ignore all `ScreenConductor.ActiveItem` properties and not try to fulfill them.